# Error in Azure WebJobs

Tags: azure-webjobs

I have created a console app and managed to upload it to the cloud, and I have scheduled it to run every 15 minutes. The console app runs for the first time with success as result and thens fails stating an error in the connection string. Could someone shed light on this please. Would be greatly apprecited.

Thanks

The error message follows:enter image description here

Make sure that you are setting a connection string named AzureJobsRuntime in your Windows Azure Website configuration with a value similar to DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=NAME;AccountKey=KEY pointing to the Windows Azure Storage account where the Windows Azure WebJobs Runtime logs are stored.
Please visit the article about configuring connection strings for more information on how you can configure connection strings in your Windows Azure Website.

Comment: Did you set `AzureJobsRuntime` as a connection stinrg (for an Azure storage account)?

Comment: I managed to get it through, you need to insert the connection string in the Azure's configuration page on your web page.

Comment: @AmitApple - Thank you very much for your reply. Yes that was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `AzureJobsRuntime` as a connection string (for an Azure storage account), you can do that on the Azure portal under: Websites --> Your Website --> CONFIGURE tab --> connection strings.

Answer (score 4):

To clarify a couple of possible gotchas (adding to the accepted answer):

Set these values by going to

```
App Services -> Your Web App -> Settings / "All Settings" -> Application Settings -> (In page under header) Connection strings
```

There you'll find Name, Value, and a Type drop down.

Name: Do NOT put your storage account name here! Rather, this is where you put `AzureWebJobsDashboard` for one connection string and on the next `AzureWebJobsStorage`. The value for these should look like:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<mysupercoolblobstorageaccountname>;AccountKey=<blahblah==>
```

[image]

-- Old Portal --
I've had problems with this before where it was fixed in the old portal, so for that sake:

Old Portal: Your website -> Configure tab -> under 'connection strings', enter two new values: a) dropdown type CUSTOM, for NAME do NOT enter the name of your storage account! rather Name is: 'AzureWebJobsDashboard' or for the other (enter two entries): 'AzureWebJobsStorage'.

Answer (score 0):

Web Job is not able to figure out the `connectionString` value in `appsettings.json` file. There could be two scenario:

1. If you are using an emulator, try adding this in your `appsettings.json` file

```
{
   "ConnectionStrings": {
      "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
      "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
    }
}
```

2. If you are trying to connect directly to your Azure portal

```
{
   "ConnectionStrings": {
       "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "url",
       "AzureWebJobsStorage": "url"
    }
 }
```