# Can't find Azure webjob's App.config in Kudu

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have an Azure webjob running which is a .NET 4.6.1 console application.

My project has an App.config file, however I can't find it in Kudu.

I'd like to see what settings are being used.

Where can I find it in Kudu?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `app.config` file will not be deployed to Azure.
- **We cannot access the app settings from Azure WebJobs directly**, we can access the ***AppSettings*** in the Azure portal.
- WebJobs are `console app`, it uses the environment variables stored in the system, which is different from the ***AppSettings*** in the Azure portal.
- Azure WebJobs uses `environment variables` instead of `configuration files`.

[image]

Please refer [Configuring Azure Web Jobs](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/16/configuring-azure-web-jobs/) and [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077330/why-do-i-need-to-configure-connection-strings-for-webjobs-in-azure-management-po?rq=1) for more information.