# Azure Web App not giving desired result

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, machine-learning, azure-blob-storage

My console application reads data from an Azure blob and executes an Azure ML model based on that data.
When the code is run from local machine, it works fine and an output file is written in another blob (as intended).
After deploying the same application as a web job(Web App in Azure), as shown in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/, it runs successfully but the output file is not written to the output blob.

Answer (score 0):

We will need more details such as your connection string settings and detailed error messages to answer your question. I would also validate the connection string setting mentioned in one of the earlier posts: [Error in Azure WebJobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767176/error-in-azure-webjobs)

Aung